# ios/xcode: View sql lite file on phone for debugging core data

Tags: sqlite, core-data

Hi I am trying to get core data to sync with a backend server dbase and running into problems.  It would really be helpful to see what is getting saved into sqllite (backing store) after various operations.  Can anyone recommend a practical way to view SQL-lite file with Xcode 6.1.1?  Searched but did not find good recommendation for phone and Xcode 6.1 with core data.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.